# How to finetune in caffe?

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe

I guess this is a great job in training models.first of all,the basic information is :I'd like to finetune a model, which I use the same dataset, but I only change the class to be trained. Ok, I have three questions:

First,if my class is included in the raw model,my classes is 6, raw classes is 20, so I change the class order in labmap file and delete some classes,but the data is of 20 classes, the question is can I change the order ?

Second,in what case can I use the raw model parameter? this maybe have a good initializtion.

Lastly,if I finetune a model,is there good advice to get a good performance?

Comment: if you want to use a subset of the labels your model was trained on, you can pick the appropriate rows of the last fully connected layer. This can be done using net surgery

Comment: @Shai Sounds great! net surgery for me is a new concept, can you have some example for me to study?

Comment: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb

Comment: @PrzemekD Thank you, I try to achieve it

Comment: @Shai I use coco dataset to train 6 classes,I trained it 10000 iterations,but the loss is mostly change from 6 to 9 (the dataset include 80 classes,I don't change the dataset, but I only want to train the first 6 classes, in lmdb files, the 6 class order is continuous,from 0 to 5,so I want to use the first 6 classes data, this can be successful?), then the learning rate is low with 0.0001,do you think is there something wrong?